# Error in Sonar rule wrt below code

Tags: java

While for below Code we are getting error in sonar:

```
 entityBuilderMap = Maps.newHashMap();
```

Giving error in sonar as:

> Dodgy - Write to static field from instance method

Can some one suggest how to fixed it out

Comment: Is your entityBuilderMap variable static?

Comment: private static Map<Class<?>, AbstractBuilder<?>> entityBuilderMap; Yes it is static .

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to a Static variable a value from an instance is a bad design practice. This can lead you in te future to bugs and problems. As a programmer we expect that static methods assign static values. If we have two different instances that assign that value as a programmer you will think that instances are changing different values but it's the same. This is very dangerous.

You can read a long description about in this SO thread.

[Writing to a static variable in an instance method, why is this a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869004/writing-to-a-static-variable-in-an-instance-method-why-is-this-a-bad-practice)